# nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/configuration-snippet annotation contains invalid word proxy_pass

Tags: nginx, kubernetes

I am trying to write the nginx ingress config for my k8s cluster.

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: blabla-data-api-ingress
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-connect-timeout: "360"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-send-timeout: "360"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-read-timeout: "360"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-body-size: 256m
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/configuration-snippet: |
      proxy_set_header Authorization $http_authorization;
      proxy_pass_header  Authorization;
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
    cert-manager.io/cluster-issuer: letsencrypt
spec:
  tls:
    - hosts:
        - blabla-data.api.staging.20-74-47-80.nip.io
      secretName: blabla-data-api-certification-staging
  rules:
    - host: blabla-data.api.staging.20-74-47-80.nip.io
      http:
        paths:
          - backend:
              serviceName: blabla-data-api
              servicePort: 80
            path: /
          - backend:
              serviceName: blabla-data-api
              servicePort: 443
            path: /
```

When I apply this config, I get this error:

```
for: "kubernetes/staging/blabla-data-api-ingress.staging.yaml": admission webhook "validate.nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io" denied the request: nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/configuration-snippet annotation contains invalid word proxy_pass
```

In fact, this piece of code used to work in the past.

I tried to add `--set controller.admissionWebhooks.enabled=false` in my `helm install nginx-ingress ingress-nginx/ingress-nginx` like that:

```
helm install nginx-ingress ingress-nginx/ingress-nginx \
    --namespace ingress \
    --set controller.replicaCount=2 \
    --set controller.nodeSelector."beta\.kubernetes\.io/os"=linux \
    --set defaultBackend.nodeSelector."beta\.kubernetes\.io/os"=linux \
    --set controller.admissionWebhooks.enabled=false
```

In this case, I don't get any error while applying this ingress config but then I get a `404` from nginx when I try to access my server through the external API.

Comment: I think it could be related to https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/user-guide/nginx-configuration/configmap/#annotation-value-word-blocklist

Comment: Which version of nginx do you have? Did you see [this issue](https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/issues/7837)? Did you use `mod_security` feature?

Comment: Yes sorry, it was exactly the issue you mentioned, thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OP has confirmed, that the issue was solved in [this github topic](https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/issues/7837)

> it was exactly the issue you mentioned, thanks for your help

This problem is related to [CVE-2021-25742](https://nvd.nist.gov/vuln/detail/CVE-2021-25742). Problem is solved based on this message:

> Hi folks we just released  [Ingress NGINX v1.0.5.](https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/releases/tag/controller-v1.0.5)  Thanks to  [@rikatz](https://github.com/rikatz)  who helped implement
> [#7874](https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/pull/7874)  which added the option to sanitize annotation inputs
>
> `annotation-value-word-blocklist`  defaults are  `"load_module,lua_package,_by_lua,location,root,proxy_pass,serviceaccount,{,},',\"`
>
> Users from mod_security and other features should be aware that some blocked values may be used by those features and must be manually unblocked by the Ingress Administrator.
>
> For more details please check  https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/user-guide/nginx-configuration/configmap/#annotation-value-word-blocklist
>
> If you have any issues with this new feature or the release please  [open a new issue](https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/issues/new/choose)  so we can track it there.